# Expressions value evaluvation

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I'm trying to create expression trees using Linq.Expressions and evaluvate them at runtime.I was wondering if there's a way to populate values based on the operator.

Example:

My expression is : `(x<=100) && (50!=y)`.What can be the values of `x` and `y`? For a true and false scenario? Is there a way to find them using `Expression` object?

Comment: You want to solve a system of (diophantine?) equations and inequations?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is going to be trivial to do!

---

One thing you might find interesting is the Pex research project from Microsoft - http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/ This is used in the pex whitebox testing plugin and in the fun http://www.pexforfun.com/ site. While not exactly your problem, I believe they do use heuristics (and some blind "trial-and-error" guesses) to try to find boundary cases for testing.

Comment: That's right.This is exactly what I was looking for but looks like I can't download a version that can be used for production.there are three options.Academic,moles only and for msdn subscribers.I have a valid licensed visual studio ultimate used for commercial purppse.

Comment: Sorry - I can give you the answers... but I can't lend you the money to join MSDN.

Comment: :-) I wanted to know if Microsoft is planning to integerate as a vs.net 2010 plug-in because as of now its still in ms labs (research).

Comment: I'm certain it will be in a future product release. So as long as you can wait...